# Odd Reflective Surface Effect

Tags: surface-deform

Very new to Blender and I need some input on this weird effect I added by accident and I'm unsure how to reverse it. Or even what it the effect is called. Usually I would just Ctrl-Z to reverse but I didn't realize it was an issue till I got out of shading and went into layout.

One of my objects has an odd reflective effect to it. It completely takes away the detail.

Any ideas?

[image][image]

Comment: Hello, maybe try a right click > Shade Flat, also in the Data panel > Geometry Data > click on Clear Custom Split Normals Data?

Comment: if it still doesn't work please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @moonboots Clearing the Custom Split Normals Data did the trick. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem of shading, the splits normals determine the shading, to reset them go into the *Data panel > Geometry Data* > and click on *Clear Custom Split Normals Data*.